# lxml installed, but not working on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, lxml

I need to validate an XML file against an XSD. To accomplish this I would like to use the [lxml library](http://lxml.de/installation.html). The problem is that even though I have `from lxml import etree` and have installed lxml to `C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\lxml\`, I'm getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asmithe\Documents\dev1\TestParse.py", line 3, in <module>
    from lxml import etree as ET_l
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

Why is this and how do I fix it? I tried adding `C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\lxml\` to the PATH variable and it didn't help. I had installed lxml using PIP.

UPDATE: When I run the script through  the interactive terminal (i.e. typing `python` in cmd) it CAN `import lxml`

Here is a simple script

```
from lxml import etree

def main():
    print('hi')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In cmd I do

```
C:\Users\dev1\Documents\test>python
Python 3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:35:05) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from lxml import etree
>>>
>>> def main():
...     print('hi')
...
>>>
>>> if __name__ == "__main__":
...     main()
...
hi
>>> exit()
```

However if I try to run it

```
> ImportLxml.py
```

then I get

```
C:\Users\dev1\Documents\test>ImportLxml.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dev1\Documents\XML test\TestImport.py", line 1, in <module>

    from lxml import etree
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

Here are all of the pythonic entries in the PATH environment variable

```
C:\Python33\;
C:\Python33\Scripts;
C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\lxml\
%ARCGISINSALLDIR%\arcpy;
```

Comment: Do you have multiple python installations in your system?

Comment: @AnandSKumar yes Python 2.7 and 3.3 (and I intend to be using 3.3). Are you asking if I have multiple installations of lxml? In the folder `C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages` there are the subfolders `lxml` and `lxml-3.4.4.dist-info`.

Comment: Can you do - `import sys; sys.version` inside the python terminal where you are getting the library import error.

Comment: @AnandSKumar it says 3.3.5. But when I do `import lxml` from command line python it works.

Comment: how are you running the script? can you add the scrpt as well?

Comment: @AnandSKumar please see update in question

Comment: Does `python ImportLxml.py` have the same problem?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `python ImportLxml.py` prints hi, so no.

Comment: Well, that's your answer -- the Python interpreter run when you just invoke `foo.py` isn't 3.3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) to use 3.3.5 as default:

```
py -3
```

Alternately -- assuming you chose to install the Python Launcher when last installing Python -- [begin your script with a shebang which the Python Launcher will recognize as requesting Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#from-a-script):

```
#! python3
```

---

If you decided not to install the Python Launcher for Windows when installing Python 3.3, see [the install documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#executing-scripts-without-the-python-launcher) for manual steps:

> Associate the correct file group with .py scripts:
>
> ```
> assoc .py=Python.File
> ```
>
> Redirect all Python files to the new executable:
>
> ```
> ftype Python.File=C:\Path\to\pythonw.exe "%1" %*
> ```

This can be used to configure the type for `Python.File` to the Python interpreter of your choice, ie. that for 3.3.5. (As a matter of good practices, `Python.File` should be pointed at `py.exe` or `python.exe`; the `pythonw.exe` example above is a direct quote from the docs, but a bad practice nonetheless).

---

Alternately, if you have a `py.exe` on disk (installed with Python 3.3) but it isn't being used, you can modify those instructions a bit:

> Associate the correct file group with .py scripts:
>
> ```
> assoc .py=Python.File
> ```
>
> Redirect all Python files to the new executable:
>
> ```
> ftype Python.File=C:\Path\to\py.exe "%1" %*
> ```

...again, adjusting the path to be appropriate for where you installed Python 3.3.x.

Comment: "Configure the Python Launcher for Windows to use 3.3.5 as default:" I can't figure out how to do this. I've added `#! python3` and `#! C:\python33\python.exe` and I tried following [these instructions](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-set-your-default-programs-windows-7) but I can't get it to use python 3 interpreter by default.

Comment: Don't follow those instructions -- follow the Python-specific instructions in the installer. There's a reason I linked 'em.

Comment: you can also, of course, use `ftype` to associate Python files with `py.exe`.

Comment: That `#! python3` doesn't work means that your current association is to (the 2.x) `python.exe` and not `py.exe`. You could also rerun the 3.3.5 installer and be sure that you have the launcher checked as an option.

Comment: `Python.File` should run python.exe (or py.exe), not pythonw.exe (or pyw.exe). The latter is typically associated with .pyw scripts and the `Python.NoConFile` file type.

Comment: @eryksun, as a matter of good practices I agree; the above was, however, a direct quote from upstream documentation, and I'm hesitant to modify such a quote.

Comment: @eryksun, ...on second thought, I've added a note next to that code sample describing that it's not to be used literally.